# Issues with jQuery UI autocomplete when form added with Javascript

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui

I can't seem to get autocomplete working with forms that I'm adding to the screen with javascript. For example, I am using my new route to render my object's form. Inside my new.js.erb in rails file I have the following:

```
$("div#container").hide().html("<%= escape_javascript render 'form' %>").fadeIn();
```

Once rendered, if I type into my input element:

```
<input id="object_name" name="object[name]" placeholder="Name" size="30" type="text">
```

And listen with it with javascript:

```
jQuery ->
  $('input#object_name').autocomplete
    source: ['Test', 'Testing', 'Test 234']
```

I get nothing as far as autocomplete is concerned. If I copy and paste this form though and have it on the screen at load (and not added dynamically with my rails new path) it will work fine. How do I get autocomplete to listen to things that are added dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear your autocomplete script is being added before your `#object_name` form element - if you ensure that you re-define your autocomplete script after `#object_name` is added to your document all should be well.